# How to append values from a 2d list to another lists and print it

Tags: python, list, append, 2d

I have this list :

```
a = [(741.0, 0), (743.0, 0), (3386.0, 0), (284577.0, 0), (290611.0, 0), (300889.0, 3), (305256.0, 0), (917458.0, 0), (917905.0, 0), (917906.0, 0), (922187.0, 0), (925852.0, 0), (1260021.0, 0), (1377096.0, 0), (1524210.0, 0), (1680657.0, 0), (1692571.0, 0), (1692645.0, 0), (1692647.0, 0), (1713958.0, 0), (1801008.0, 0), (1818975.0, 0), (1858888.0, 0), (1880544.0, 0), (1880898.0, 0), (1880899.0, 0), (1880900.0, 0), (1881062.0, 0), (1881073.0, 0), (1881240.0, 0), (1881433.0, 0), (1881434.0, 0), (1881435.0, 0), (1881436.0, 0), (1881438.0, 0), (1958358.0, 0), (1958478.0, 0), (1958479.0, 0), (1958481.0, 0), (1967310.0, 0)]
```

i want to make 2 lists...the first one will have the first values from each list above,`b[0] = [741.0,743.0,3386.0,....]` and the second one will have the second values, `a = [(j,k,l),(j1,k1,l1),...]`. I want to do it with for so that if `a = [(j,k,l),(j1,k1,l1),...]` i would create 3 lists and not 2...i have this code but it doesnt work the way i want:

Code Sample :

```
b = []
for i in range(N):
    b.append([])
    for j in range(R):
        b[i].append([])
        for k in range(0,M,2):
            b[i][j].append(j - k)
print b
```

N = 2,R = 40, M = 80 (2x40)

Comment: Please claritfy what is your expected output

Comment: i want 2 lists...the first one b[0] = [741.0,743.0,3386.0,....1967310.0], the first values in every list of "a" and the second one b[1] = [0,0,0,0,0,....,0], the second values in every list of "a"

Comment: @ThanosSmar what are `(j, k , l)` then? Do you want to group every 3 numbers in 2nd list?

Comment: `a` is a list of tuples, you should learn python basics

Comment: this is an example...if "a" had the form a = [(j,k,l),(j1,k1,l1)] then i would want to create 3 lists, b[0] = [j,j1] , b[1] = [k,k1] and b[2] = [k,k1]

Comment: @mvelay so what i am trying to do isn't possible?

Comment: @ThanosSmar for your particular example. I think this is sufficient `b = [[elt[0] for elt in a],[elt[1] for elt in a]]` .But this is a wort method of coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more pythonic approach consists in using list comprehension:

```
for i in range(len(a[0])):
    b.append([elt[i] for elt in a])
```